# What is the best way to connect a UWP app to a remote database?

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp, raspberry-pi3

I am working in a new project in **Windows IOT** using a **Raspberry pi 3 model B**. I am going to use multiple devices to connect to a database I will create and post data. My question is what is the best way to implement this? Can I connect to a remote **SQLite** database with a UWP app or should I use something different?
I am a total newbie so please keep it simple. :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a traditional RDBMS such as SQL Server or MySQL for your backend.  SQLite has a nice page [here](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) that discusses use cases.  Since you are going to have multiple client devices communicating with a central database, you may run into concurrency problems that would be avoided using a traditional RDBMS.  SQLite would be ideal for an internal database inside your Raspberry Pi though.

I also, personally, like to put something like a WebAPI service in front of the database if I'm exposing it to the internet.  That way if data access logic needs to change, the change can be made without redeploying to all the client devices.

Comment: Nice, I think I will go with the MySQL solution.